# Statistics about voting to close and actually closed questions

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, statistics, data-explorer

Is there a way to see how many of the questions I voted to close have actually been closed - and further on how many of the closed ones have later been deleted?

I've tried those two queries, but both return 0 as a result (but I've voted to close quite a lot and there are actually closed ones... )

```
select count(Posts.Id) from Posts
  inner join Votes on Posts.Id = Votes.PostId
where Votes.UserId = '3993662' 
  and Votes.VoteTypeId = 6
  and Posts.ClosedDate is not null;


select count(PostFeedback.Id) from PostFeedback
  inner join Votes on PostFeedback.PostId = Votes.PostId
where Votes.UserId = '3993662' 
  and Votes.VoteTypeId = 6;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only partially get that data if the question was actually closed because at that moment the posthistory table stores a row with posthistorytypeid = 10 and records in the text column the voters. The content is a JSON structure. See for the explanation of the JSON [my MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234794/158100).

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/642391?UserId=3993662) shows the questions that have been closed by you successfully and the current state of the question.

```sql
select  ph.postid as [Post Link]
     , ph.creationdate [was closed at]
     , case 
       when p.closeddate is null then 'now open' 
       else 'still closed' 
       end [current state]
from posthistory ph
left outer join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
where posthistorytypeid = 10
and text like '%"Id":' + cast(##userid:int## as nvarchar) + ',%'
order by ph.creationdate
```

You can't query for questions you cast a close vote on but didn't make it to get the question actually closed. That data is not in the public schema.

Comment: You could instead infer from the close votes casted from your profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure

Comment: @Teemu you sure you are looking at the closure tab?

Comment: @Braiam Hmm... actually no. You're right, the own deleted answers are listed in the deletion tab.

Comment: @Braiam any way to filter the list of your profile to get directly the list of questions that didn't get closed?

Comment: @Cœur nope, you'll need to write a userscript to scrape your profile/actions/votes page

Comment: @Cœur it says so in the very same title. Look for [on hold] [closed]